# My JavaScript doesn't work in Chrome, no errors, works elsewhere

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

My code below seems to work in all browsers except for Chrome. I'm not getting any errors, but I'm also not seeing the table I expect. Any help to make it work in Chrome would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ofensas</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><br/><br></p>
 <div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
   <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Descrição</th>
    <th>Número</th>
    <th>ID</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
  </table>
 
 </div>
 

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" ></script>
 <script>
 $.getJSON("exemplo.json",function(data){
  var items = [];
  $.each(data, function(key, val){
   items.push("<tr>");
   items.push("<td name='" + key + "'>" + val.offense_name +"</td>");
   items.push("<td nuemro='" + key + "'>" + val.count + "</td>");
   items.push("<td name='" + key + "'>" + val.offense_id + "</td>");
   items.push("</tr>");
  
  
  });
  $("<tbody/>", {html: items.join("")}).appendTo("table");
 
 });
 
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" - the single most unhelpful thing you could say.  **What** doesn't work... what should it do... what does it do that it shouldn't??  Have you checked for any errors in the console tools?

Comment: It should show a table and it shows on the browsers I tested so far with the exception of chrome. Also no console errors.

Comment: I get a lot of errors when I click the Run Code Snippet button in your question. You should pay attention to what sort of code the demo editor asks you to put in each box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're including the `bootstrap.min.css` file in a `script` tag. Other browsers may overlook that; however, Chrome isn't, because it's not valid. You're already including it properly in the head of the document, so just delete that line.

Also, if you open your original code with Chrome Dev Tools > Console, you should see:

> bootstrap.min.css:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Here's a basic example that uses a mock api response to accomplish what you're doing.

```js
const apiResponse = {
  data: [
    { "count": 42, "offense_id": 42, "offense_name": "Bird Flu" },
    { "count": 56, "offense_id": 56, "offense_name": "Volvulus" }
  ]
}
var items = [];
$.each(apiResponse.data, function(key, val) {
  items.push("<tr>");
  items.push("<td name='" + key + "'>" + val.offense_name + "</td>");
  items.push("<td nuemro='" + key + "'>" + val.count + "</td>");
  items.push("<td name='" + key + "'>" + val.offense_id + "</td>");
  items.push("</tr>");
});
$("<tbody/>", {html: items.join("")}).appendTo("table");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th>Número</th>
        <th>ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```